# map function returns item even if condition is not true

Tags: javascript

Here's my code:

```
//input = aaaaaaa,                ddd,            ,    
 asdsad,

newUser =
users
  .split(',')
  .map(item => {
    item = item.trim();
    if(item.length > 0) {
      return item;
    }
}).join();

//output = aaaaaaa,ddd,,asdsad,
```

So my question is why if item has 0 length is returned from map function? Am I missing something obvious?

//EDIT:

Yeah, now its removoing empty strings but what about white spaces? My result still looks like this:

`asdasdasd      ,       aa`

I want to have:

`asdasdasd,aa`

Comment: You are confusing ```map``` with ```filter```.

Comment: with map, you could change the value, with filter, you can omit items.

Comment: And please post compilable code.

Answer (score 1):

As per doc of [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on **every element** in the calling array.

So using map you can perform some opration on each element, you can not omit any element.

If you want to omit some element based on some condtion then use [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

For your case you can first use `map()` for triming all element then use `filter()` to removed element whose length is not `>0`.

```js
var input = "aaaaaaa,                ddd,            ,asdsad   ";

var output = input.split(',').map(item => {
    item = item.trim();
    return item;
}).filter(item => {
    return item.length > 0;
}).join();

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `length` of the array returned by `map()` will always be equal to the length of orignal array. When you want to remove elements of array accoring to condition use `filter()` .

In the particular case you can remove white spaces first from the string and then remove two or more adjacent commas with single comma.

```js
let input = 'aaaaaaa,                ddd,            ,     asdsad,'
let res = input.replace(/\s+/g,'').replace(/,{2,}/,',');
console.log(res)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think the author don't want empty strings between commas to be parts of the final result.

Comment: I also think that he wants the excess of spaces to be removed. Like `map` the string first then `filter` it. The author was not very clear in this post.

Comment: Yeah your first solution was fine, but there were two consecutive commas instead of one (because the *void* between them needed to be removed).

Comment: @KévinBibollet Yeah you are right I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use String replace and regex to remove all white space

```js
let input = 'aaaaaaa,                ddd,            ,    asdsad,';
let newData = input.replace(/ /g, '');;
console.log(newData)
```

Alternatively you can use reduce function. Inside reduce callback check the the length of the string and if condition satisfies then push it with the accumulator. Finally use `join` to cancat using `,` delimiter

```js
let users = " aaaaaaa,                ddd,            ,   asdsad"
let newUser = users.split(',')
  .reduce(function(acc, curr) {
    if (curr.trim().length > 0) {
      acc .push(curr.trim());
    }
    return acc;
  },[]).join(',')
console.log(newUser)
```